# what is the maximum file size to be uploaded in neo4j using LOAD CSV functionality

Tags: file-upload, neo4j

What is the maximum file size that can be uploaded into a Neo4J database using their LOAD CSV functionality? And is that dependent on the system specifications?
I have successfully uploaded files containing 500K records (about 180MB) but the upload crashes when trying a 4.8GB file with a java heap space error

Comment: Are you loading with USING PERIODIC COMMIT?

Comment: I was not. That did seem to improve performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using `LOAD CSV` with `PERIODIC COMMIT` you need to be aware of the `eager`-problem. Depending on the action you perform the query plan might show up an element containing `eager`.

The query plan can be inspectecd via `EXPLAIN LOAD CSV .....` (strip off the `PERIODIC COMMIT` for inspection).

`eager` basically means that Cypher thinks that there might be cross-row dependencies and therefore the statement cannot be executed in multiple transaction and `PERIODIC COMMIT` is deactivated. So your CSV file is processed in one single transaction.

But there's a way to solve this: [Neo4j APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) allows you to use a combination of `apoc.periodic.iterate` and `apoc.load.csv`, see the following complex example importing some twitter data from a csv file:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('call apoc.load.csv("file:/tmp/all.csv", {
 sep:";", 
 header:true, 
 mapping:{
  retweets:{type:"int"},
  favorites:{type:"int"},
  date:{type:"int"},
  mentions:{array:true, arraySep:" "},
  hashtags:{array:true, arraySep:" "}
 }
}) yield map',
"with {map} as map 
merge (u:User{username:map.username})
merge (t:Tweet {id:map.id})
on create set t.text=map.text, t.date=map.date, t.retweet=map.retweets, t.favorite=map.favorites, t.link=map.permalink
merge (k:Keyword{name:map.keyword})
merge (t)-[:HAS_KW]->(k)
merge (u)-[:SENT_TWEET]->(t)
FOREACH (m IN [x in map.mentions WHERE x<>''] |
   MERGE (mentioned:User {username:substring(m,1)})
   MERGE (t)-[:MENTIONS]->(mentioned)
)
FOREACH (h in [x in map.hashtags WHERE x<>''] |
   MERGE (ht:HashTag{name:h})
   MERGE (t)-[:USES_HASHTAG]->(ht)
)
", {batchSize:5000, parallel:false});
```